# I want to 'undo' adding myself to docker group

Tags: permissions, docker, user-management, adduser

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

I installed Docker from [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/docker). Then i started running the commands as recommended on the page, because i wanted to be able to run it as a normal user.These are the command that i run:

```
 sudo addgroup --system docker
 sudo adduser $USER docker
 newgrp docker
 sudo snap disable docker
 sudo snap enable docker
```

And after completing running them all, i saw the warning on the same page:

> Warning: if you add your user to the docker group, it will have similar power as the root user. For details on how this impacts security in your system, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface

Since i am an inexperienced user, this warning got me a little scared.

My question is, how do i undo that? How do i revert everything back to the moment before i started installing Docker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the `sudo adduser $USER docker` command with the following:

```
sudo deluser $USER docker
```

However I don't think this is necessary. I have no experience with Docker, but adding yourself to any group doesn't automatically make you root. It rather gives you the ability to elevate to root if needed - which you probably have anyway, if you are able to use sudo :)